# grid refresh after updating the data set in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have a datagrid view control that is tied to a data reader.
MY GridView Like This:

```
CarID      RequestedTime
571         09/18/2013
572         09/19/2013
```

this data is coming depend upon the status.i have a stored procedure. that wil take only status 3.then i am loading the grid view.
after few minute the carid 571 changed the statu=4  that time automatically i want to remove that particular recored id from my data grid view .i am filling data grid view like this:

```
     Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("IBS_RequestedPerLocation", con.connect)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
 If dr("Car_Id") Is DBNull.Value Then
                        carid = "null"
                    Else
                        carid = dr("Car_Id")
                    End If
                    If dr("RequstedTime") Is DBNull.Value Then

                        datetime = ""
                    Else
                        datetime = dr("RequstedTime")
                    End If
                    If dr("KRRT") Is DBNull.Value Then
                        krrt = 0
                    Else
                        krrt = dr("KRRT")
                    End If
                    If dr("Value") Is DBNull.Value Then
                        value = 0
                    Else
                        value = dr("Value")
                    End If
                    Dim row0 As String() = {carid, datetime, krrt, value}
                    DgvRequested.Rows.Insert(0, row0)
                        End While
```

Answer (score 0):

just use DgvRequested.Refresh()
it will refresh gridview data